# Out of range при работе substringWithRange

Tags: xcode, iphone, objective-c

Прошу помощи: имею простецкий код в котором строковой переменной string присваивается значение @"000000000"

Потом идет код и при выполнении

```
[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(9,1)]
```

вылетает краш с ошибкой
'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {9, 1} out of bounds; string length 9'

Не могу понять почему out of bounds?
Вроде девять символов.

Подскажите кто знает

Comment: если будешь задавать 

[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8,1)];

то ставь проверку на кол-во символов в стринге.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([string length] - 1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

символов - то 9, вот тока с 0 счет начинается ^_^, следовательно последний индекс будет 8.